# How to install Python packages from the tar.gz file without using pip install

Tags: python, installation, package

Long story short my work computer has network constraints which means trying to use `pip install` in cmd just leads to timing out/not finding package errors.

For example; when I try to `pip install seaborn`:
[image]

Instead I have tried to download the tar.gz file of the packages I want, however, I do not know how to install them. I've extracted the files from the tar.gz file and there is a "setup" file within but it's not doing much for me.

If someone could explain how to install python packages in this manner without using `pip install` on windows that would be amazing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks to the answers below combined I've got it working.

- First needed to unpack the tar.gz file into a folder.
- Then before running `python setup.py install` had to point cmd towards the correct folder. I did this by `pushd C:\Users\absolutefilepathtotarunpackedfolder`
- Then run `python setup.py install`

Thanks Tales Padua & Hugo Honorem

Comment: Can you edit the PATH variables of your machine? If so, you can add python to it, and use python anywhere without need to use pushd

Comment: Actually you don't have to extract the tar.gz file to install it. Take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37393114/3375713)

Answer (score 224):

You may use `pip` for that without using the network. See [in the docs](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) (search for "Install a particular source archive file"). Any of those should work:

```
pip install relative_path_to_seaborn.tar.gz    
pip install absolute_path_to_seaborn.tar.gz    
pip install file:///absolute_path_to_seaborn.tar.gz
```

Or you may uncompress the archive and use `setup.py` directly with either `pip` or `python`:

```
cd directory_containing_tar.gz
tar -xvzf seaborn-0.10.1.tar.gz
pip install seaborn-0.10.1
python setup.py install
```

Of course, you should also download required packages and install them the same way before you proceed.

Comment: This gives the following error: `You must give at least one requirement to install (maybe you meant "pip install file:///absolute path.."?)`

Comment: and I have actually entered the path in case you're wondering!

Comment: If you can download on another machine and bring them over, it's possible to download each dependency you need and install them in this manner in such an order that the desired package has all dependencies met and does not need a network connection anymore.

I.e., `A` depends on `B`. So install `B`, then `A`.

Answer (score 38):

You can install a tarball without extracting it first. Just navigate to the directory containing your `.tar.gz` file from your command prompt and enter this command:

```
pip install my-tarball-file-name.tar.gz
```

I am running python 3.4.3 and this works for me. I can't tell if this would work on other versions of python though.

Comment: Running this on python 3.4.3 and pip 9.0.1 I get an error relating to a temp file:

`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-anjip21-build/setup.py`

running on Jessie (raspberry pi 3)

Comment: @Magic See the [examples in official docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#examples). So it _should_ work. From the error message you showed it seems the tarball you are trying to install isn't following proper file naming conventions.

Comment: pip install *.tar.gz will install all the packages in the directory... just trying to help:)

Answer (score 8):

Install it by running

```
python setup.py install
```

Better yet, you can download from github. Install git via `apt-get install git` and then follow this steps:

```
git clone https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn.git
cd seaborn
python setup.py install
```

Comment: `No such file or directory` 
This could be to do with the setup of my files and folders. Python isn't gonna be in the default place Python would normally install

Comment: unpack from tar, go to the folder where the setup.py is, and then run the command above

Comment: Do I need to amend the code above to point it directly to where the unpacked tar is? Cos I'm still getting `no such file or directory`

Comment: Unpack the tar.gz to somewhere. Then, from the terminal, go to the folder where you extracted it. You need to be on the folder where setup.py is, and then run this command

Comment: Unfortunatley github is blocked on my work computer!! I've got it working now though; thanks

Comment: You can also use [pip + git](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#git) but I assumed network issues ruled out this option.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't wanted to use PIP install atall, then you could do the following:

1) Download the package
2) Use 7 zip for unzipping tar files. ( Use 7 zip again until you see a folder by the name of the package you are looking for. Ex: wordcloud)

[image: Folder by Name 'wordcloud']

3) Locate Python library folder where python is installed and paste the 'WordCloud' folder itself there

[image: Python Library folder]

4) Success !! Now you can import the library and start using the package.

[image]

Comment: This works perfect for situations where using pip generates `error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')`

Comment: I was getting a whole host of different errors using the other solutions -- this was the only solution that worked for me

Comment: Ciao I tried with the openpyxl-3.1.2.tar.gz  so as you suggested I've unzipped untill I got the folder without tar.gz, and copied it into the python\lib. Once I've done this I've tried to run the import openpyxl and it didn't work. Error received: cannot import name 'load_workbook' from 'openpyxl'

Answer (score 5):

For those of you using python3 you can use:

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible for you to use `sudo apt-get install python-seaborn` instead? Basically tar.gz is just a zip file containing a setup, so what you want to do is to unzip it, cd to the place where it is downloaded and use `gunzip -c seaborn-0.7.0.tar.gz | tar xf -` for linux. Change dictionary into the new seaborn unzipped file and execute `python setup.py install`

Comment: Okey, so he could use another unzipper like 7-zip, it's pretty irrelevant what unzipper he uses..

Comment: might be, anyhow, the instructions are: unzip the folder -> change dictionary in your command line into that folder -> execute `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was working on an Oracle Enterprise Linux 6 (OEL 6) system that had Python 2.6.6 installed. I downloaded the tar file from the Python Package Index (PyPI) and installed it using the easy_install command. In my case, I was trying to install the virtualenv package. I followed these steps to install it:

1. Download the tar file from pypi. Eg: [virtualenv](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/15.2.0/#files)

   `wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b1/72/2d70c5a1de409ceb3a27ff2ec007ecdd5cc52239e7c74990e32af57affe9/virtualenv-15.2.0.tar.gz`
2. Install the package from tar file.

   `easy_install virtualenv-15.2.0.tar.gz`