# How to install an older version of python

Tags: python

How can I install python 3.4 (Windows version) when a newer version (3.5.1) is now available.  My app specifically is looking for 3.4.  I can't seem to find a download for any of the older versions.

Comment: https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: I tried that and unless I'm missing something (quite possible), when I click on "download" for that release it takes me to the page with info about the release but there is no download button.

Comment: See the "Files" section below.

Answer (score 27):

All the answers here are outdated since `Python.org` doesn't host installers for older versions of Python anymore, only source code.
And building Python on Windows is not really a walk in the park...

My solution: **Pyenv**.

It's crossplatform (Linux, MacOS, Windows: where it's called `pyenv-win`), and you can with it automatically install among a very large list of Python versions.

There aren't ALL python versions existing but the list is already very big.

Installation pf pyenv is quite easy if you use `chocolatey`.

Then:

`pyenv install --list` : all the versions that you can install.

and then:

`pyenv install 3.9.0` for example.

Comment: Not true, Python does host older versions installers. https://stackoverflow.com/a/70014002/2119941

Comment: For install pyenv see this doc : [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv)

Answer (score 24):

## Python.org DOES host installers for older versions

For example if you want to download version 3.4 you just have to find major release which is:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.4/

In case release is only bugfix you want be able to find installer so than just change last digit in url until you find release with installer, so

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.4.**x**/

change **x** until you find installer for your release.

Optionally- than you can find latest bugfix and try to install it [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install/37393114).

Comment: you saved me a lot of time, thanks

Comment: Amazing! All this time I thought with my windows systems I would have to keep up with the latest and greatest.

Answer (score 11):

**To download older version of python :**

1. go to https://www.python.org
2. hover over downloads button and click on [View the full list of downloads.](https://www.python.org/downloads/)
3. scroll down a bit and click on the version you want [image: (preview)]
4. then scroll to the bottom (the files section)
5. if you are a 64-bit user then click on **Windows x86-64 executable installer**
6. if you are a 32-bit user then click on **Windows x86 executable installer**
   [image: (preview)]

after downloading it, you can install it.

Comment: If only it was so simple... Many versions only offer source tarballs.

Comment: Its a little bit different in 2021 august, you need to go downloads and than to 'windows' option not "view full downloads", after going to windows option you can download the executable installer by scrolling down and searching for the right version of python.

Comment: Yes. For example, for python 3.6.X releases only 3.6.8 and older have exe files

Comment: Tried to install v3.7.8 and the installer actually doesn't let you install it if you have a newer version installed. It throws an error.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest thing would be to install conda on your machine and run the following command

```
$ conda create -n py34 python=3.4
```

Here’s a very good datacamp tutorial about installing conda on your windows machine: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows

Comment: You don't need conda to install Python, when you can simply, only install Python. Besides, you need Python 3.4 for Conda to create a 3.4 environment, so whats the point?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm fairly certain you don't need to install Python 3.4 separately, and that Anaconda / Miniconda handles installation of different python versions for you. I think conda is worth mentioning, considering all that it provides. Some people, myself included, prefer conda to pyenv or virtualenv

Comment: Thank you @bug_spray i was about to say what you just said :)

Comment: My point is that conda is a Python based, cli, so it's effectively achieving the same goal as pyenv, for example. Virtualenv definitely is bound to the Python version its ran by. But my other point is that which python installation would it be managing after it installed another version?

Answer (score 5):

The simplest platform independend solution to that is:

**A) The oldschool way**

1) Go to the Python [site](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-344/) and grab the Files you need

2) Unpack and make sure the execution path from your environment points for Python to the destination directory.

**B)**
Or use: https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

**C)** http://conda.pydata.org/docs/py2or3.html seems to do a similar job.

Comment: I'm not quite savy enough to do (A) but I will try (b). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which ...hat downvoted here and for _what reason_?

Answer (score 1):

1- You can use UBUNTU, switching between python is easy.

2- pyenv helps you to switch between versions of python.

3- virtualenv can be used.

Comment: Hi Swarnim Singh,
I understand you're new here, so I'd recommend reading the guidlines on how to answer questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.
In a case like this: you're giving duplicate answers half a decade after similar answers were given before. I would suggest expanding and giving examples along with your answers, but this is low quality

Answer (score 0):

I had to download it from an unofficial website as the official sites offer only the source and the exe for Windows.( was trying to download 3.5.x)

Answer (score 0):

As of Sep.2023, I installed 3.9.0 on windows 10 with pyenv-win.

install pyenv-win, then from there install older versions.
https://github.com/pyenv-win/pyenv-win
The readme is easy to follow.