# how to install packages without direct internet considered packages dependencies?

Tags: python, dependencies, installation

I want to install packages without using the Internet.

I searched for it. For example, using [this reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install):

`pip install relative_path_to_seaborn.tar.gz`

But I think if I can not consider package dependencies , it can not be installed properly.

In R, using library miniCRAN, consider dependencies.

So how to install packages without the Internet connection and taking into account the package dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

One of the simpler methods it to use `pip wheel` if you are going to install on the same platform.

```
$ mkvirtualenv -p python3 foo
$ mkdir baz ; cd baz
$ pip wheel pip wheel numpy pandas seaborn
```

Will download the dependencies to the local directory.

```
$ pip install ./*.whl
Installing collected packages: six, cycler, kiwisolver, pyparsing, pytz, python-dateutil, matplotlib, pandas, scipy, seaborn
```

You can also use `pip download` but it is less likely to grab all of the needed sub-dependencies.

Where as the output from `pip wheel` will show:

```
  Saved ./Glances-2.11.1-cp36-none-any.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas)
```

You can copy or specify a directory to save to then install with:

```
$ pip install --no-index --find-links=/srv/foo/wheels project
```

If you have larger needs you can use projects like [devpi](https://github.com/devpi/devpi) or [pyenv](http://pyenv) or consider using [fpm](https://fpm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro.html) to create rpms, debs, pkgs etc...

Comment: thanks, but i can not understand the method... how to use it...did you know easy method like miniCRAN packges in R??  miniCRAN provide related packages.tar.gz considered dependencies in directed local repository.

Comment: `pip wheel` is similar here is a link to the docs.

https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#installation-bundles