# Python3: A better way of installing to site-packages than drag and drop?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I'd like to share some code with colleagues but I don't want to put it on PyPI or anything.

I thought I could do this by following [the docs](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/), but it doesn't seem to work.

The file structure is

```
/my_package
    /my_package
        __init__.py
        my_module.py
    setup.py
    README.md
    LICENSE
```

In particular, doing any of

```
pip3 install the_package_containing_setup.tar.gz
pip3 install . # from the same directory as setup.py
python3 setup.py install # from the same directory as setup.py
```

results in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/my_package-py3.egg.info` being made (I'm on Mac, with Python 3.6.5 installed from Homebrew). However, running `pip3 freeze` prints `my_package=0.01`.

In short, I'd like a way to do what [the most-voted post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install) does, where I somehow put everything into some sort of zip file or tar ball and just have my colleagues run `pip3 install tarball.tar.gz`.

Is there a way to do this? Currently I just tell them to unzip the file and then drag and drop it into their project's `site-packages` folder.

Comment: So there is no folder called `my_package` in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/` when you use any of these commands? Can you try `import mypackage; mypackage.__file__`? Whats the output you get?

Comment: No, I can't find such a file there or anywhere else. `import mypackage` fails with `ModuleNotFoundError`.

Comment: Packaging the code to a source dist is being done via `python setup.py sdist` command from terminal. After the command finishes, check out the emerged file in the `dist` directory, either `tar.gz` or `tar.bz2`  or `zip` archive (depends on what you define in the setup script). This file is supposed to be installable via `pip install file.tar.gz`; if you miss any modules after the installation, it is likely you have misconfigured the package in the setup script. If this is the case, add the contents of `setup.py` to the question.