# Installing dlib on anaconda with python=3.6 build failed

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6

I downloaded dlib-19.19.0.tar.gz file from https://pypi.org/simple/dlib/ website. I tried to install using [How to install Python packages from the tar.gz file without using pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install) these methods. But none of it worked for me. 
This is my anaconda info:

```
(base) C:\Users\Krishna Rohith>conda info

 active environment : base
active env location : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\Anaconda3
        shell level : 1
   user config file : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\.condarc
populated config files : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\.condarc
      conda version : 4.8.0
conda-build version : 3.18.11
     python version : 3.6.9.final.0
   virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
   base environment : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\Anaconda3  (writable)
       channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                      https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
      package cache : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\Anaconda3\pkgs
                      C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\.conda\pkgs
                      C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
   envs directories : C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\Anaconda3\envs
                      C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\.conda\envs
                      C:\Users\Krishna Rohith\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
           platform : win-64
         user-agent : conda/4.8.0 requests/2.22.0 CPython/3.6.9 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
      administrator : False
         netrc file : None
       offline mode : False
```

I used only one method of installing. I unpacked tar.gz file and from that folder i run python setup.py install and it shows this error while installing:

[As you can what's the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMcxq.png)

[This is that extension and show some cmake errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQsi1.png)

And my cmake installed in anaconda: 
cmake                     3.14.0               h33f27b4_0    anaconda

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If cmake is not installed then first install it using following command

```
conda install -c anaconda cmake
```

else

Just install dlib:

```
conda install -c conda-forge dlib
```

Now, check whether it is installed or not

```
>>import dlib
>>dlib.__version__
```

If no errors then you installed dlib successfully

else please try again cause there may be issue for first time installation.

Comment: Yeah I know but didn't update the answer, anyway. Thank you.

Comment: This suggestion also work on WSL (UBUNTU)

Answer (score 0):

Thank You for this: [dlib installation on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912372/dlib-installation-on-windows-10)
I didn't find it in the first place else I wouldn't post this question. Anyways Thank you Marco D.G for your replay on this it helped me solve this issue with first run. Hope you guys also get solved with this answer. And i just ran: pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/da/06/bd3e241c4eb0a662914b3b4875fc52dd176a9db0d4a2c915ac2ad8800e9e/dlib-19.7.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl#md5=b7330a5b2d46420343fbed5df69e6a3f
this in my conda.