# python venv : In a Win laptop, I need to create a venv dir, and ftp that dir to redhat

Tags: python, python-venv

In short:

How to trick python3.exe to bring in linux dependencies into a "env-lin" folder that I can later copy to myproj/env-lin in a linux box?

Constraints:

- only one windows machine - no VMs, no docker.
- one unix machine with high restriction, no internet, no access to py dependencies. The py project need two dependencies, those dependences must be fetched in a WIN-Laptop somehow. Later I'll copy it over to the linux server

Is there a way I can create below venv in my windows laptop? and copy over env-lin to linux server?

```
/myproj

 /env-win

 /env-lin
```

Comment: Assuming you have compiled dependencies, then those would be OS specific and cannot be copied. You don't necessarily need internet access, but a local pypi mirror would be beneficial

Comment: You can download the source files `package-name-X.tar.gz` and just copy them to your linux machine. Then, you can install them with `pip`. No need for local PyPI server or internet connection. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36014474/3015186) for example.