# eric installation for python 27

Tags: python, pip, code-editor

I am using Python 2.7.18, and I would rather use Eric as editor to my code, but I downloaded eric6 and when I want to install it says eric6 is for python 3.5 and upper versions.
Does anyone know which w=version of Eric is compatible with Python 2.7 ?
I also tried installing it using pip!! But it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

After going through the PyPI release history, the latest version of Eric that is compatible with Python 2 is 19.9. Here is the link: https://pypi.org/project/eric-ide/19.9/

You can install using:

```
pip install eric-ide==19.9
```

There are more comprehensive instructions on the PyPI page, and they recommend using a virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I used this command "pip install eric-ide==19.9" it says : "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement eric-ide==19.9 (from versions: none)"

Comment: @VahidTalebi When I used pip, it tries to install the python3 wheel file, so you might have to manually download the tar.gz from the pypi release files and use setup.py to install.

Comment: I did it also, when I launched the setup.py to install, a black window like command windows opens and immediately closes!

Comment: Try downloading and then using pip to install. Remember to use pip2.7 not 3

Comment: The pip version is "pip 20.3.4" I also downloaded wheel file for that and tried to install using pip... same error occurred...

Comment: I meant the pip python version. Also, you can install a downloaded tar file. See here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install