# How can I upgrade the Python version if I only have the .tgz or the .tar.xz file?

Tags: python, windows, upgrade

I see that Python recently upgraded their 3.7 and 3.8 version of the language, but they only offer  the .tgz and the .tar.xz files, not the executable installer. How can I upgrade to these versions? I tried what was said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install) without any success. But the question was asked 5 years ago so I am thinking that things have changed since then.

Comment: The article you linked as about installing python _packages_ from source, not Python itself. Check out [How to Build Python From Source Code](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#how-to-build-python-from-source-code) instead to see how to build Python in Linux distributions for which no package with binaries is available.

Comment: Hm I see in your tags you mentioned `windows`. Now I'm confused, for Windows there is an installer and even an app in the Microsoft store, see [How to Install Python on Windows](https://realpython.com/installing-python/#how-to-install-python-on-windows). Can you explain why you think there is only a source code tarball available? Where did you get this information?

Comment: @CherryDT About the tarball, I got the information from here: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3811/ 

I put the windows tag because I don't use Python for Unix or Linux

Comment: Oh now I understand what you mean, you are talking about 3.8.**11** in particular. To quote the page: "Python 3.8 isn't receiving regular bugfixes anymore, and binary installers are no longer provided for it. Python 3.8.10 was the last full bugfix release of Python 3.8 with binary installers." - Meaning if you want binaries, either install 3.8.10 or the recommended version from the 3.9.x branch. If you need to use 3.8.11, check out the [build instructions for Windows](https://devguide.python.org/setup/#windows).

Comment: See also the [CPython readme](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/PCbuild/readme.txt#L57)

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it is for 3.8.11, but I phrased the question to generalize for all the versions.

Comment: But other versions don't have this exception. 3.8.10 (which was launched before 3.8.x's end-of-life) has a regular installer: https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-3810/

Comment: 3.7.11 also has it

Comment: ..... OK I see now - I misread the question. I read it as "they updated 3.7 **to** 3.8" for some reason, so I thought it's about upgrading from 3.7 to 3.8 and not about upgrading from 3.7.10 to 3.7.11 and 3.8.10 to 3.8.11 - my mistake. It all makes more sense now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method:

`conda create --name project-env python=3.x`

You can also look at an alternative method to install python versions [Install python version](https://realpython.com/intro-to-pyenv)