# Python add .tar.gz file to library

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04, mariadb-connect-engine

New mariaDB-Version as download available. But:
I have downloaded this [https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/] mariadb-connector-c-3.2.4-ubuntu-focal-amd64.tar.gz. Unfortunately, it's a .tar.gz. I have no idea how to insert it into the Python library?

Is there a version that can be installed via pip3?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Python packages from the tar.gz file without using pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36014334/how-to-install-python-packages-from-the-tar-gz-file-without-using-pip-install)

Comment: Have you tried `pip3 install <name of tar>`? Did that exit with an error?